# Configure HTTP Proxy for Containers in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes v1.18.3 cluster and the workers have a Docker v19.03.6 dameon.

I'm looking for a way to automatically inject the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` to every container that Kubernetes creates.

I tried creating a `~/.docker/config.json` file, but it didn't work.

What would be the proper way to accomplish it?

Comment: 1) can you please explain the use case; 2) show how you configured ~/.docker/config.json

Comment: did you find any solution for this? it looks like settings from .docker/config.json  does not get picked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was interested in your case, even reproduced with the same docker and k8s versions...
Used official [Configure Docker to use a proxy server](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/) documentation to set proxy for docker in `~/.docker/config.json`

> Configure the Docker client On the Docker client, create or edit the
>   file ~/.docker/config.json in the home directory of the user which
>   starts containers. Add JSON such as the following, substituting the
>   type of proxy with httpsProxy or ftpProxy if necessary, and
>   substituting the address and port of the proxy server. You can
>   configure multiple proxy servers at the same time.

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
}
```

> Save the file.
>        When you create or start new containers, the environment variables are set automatically within the container.

My config was:

```
{
  "proxies": {
    "default": {
      "httpProxy": "http://user:pass@my.proxy.domain.com",
      "httpsProxy": "http://user:pass@my.proxy.domain.com"
    }
  }
}
```

So basically after setting above in `~/.docker/config.json`, the proxy-server will be automatically used when starting a brand new containers.

In my case that worked, I can verify that by using cli and creating e.g busybox container.

```
$ docker container run --rm busybox env
HTTP_PROXY=http://user:pass@my.proxy.domain.com
http_proxy=http://user:pass@my.proxy.domain.com
HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:pass@my.proxy.domain.com
https_proxy=http://user:pass@my.proxy.domain.com
HOME=/root
```

Please keep in mind that there should be issues with next part:

> On the Docker client, create or edit the file ~/.docker/config.json **in
>   the home directory of the user which starts containers**.

Be careful with `USER` you use and make sure your `HOME` env is set to correct one.

Links to github almost similar issue and ways to resolve:

1) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45487#issuecomment-312042754

> I dug into this a bit and the issue for me was that the HOME
>   environment variable was empty when kubelet was launched through a
>   systemd unit. While it's not documented this way, loading the
>   configuration from /root/docker/config.json or /root/.dockercfg
>   requires that HOME=/root
>
> Setting User=root in the [Service] declaration fixed it up for me.

2) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45487#issuecomment-378116386

3) https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45487#issuecomment-464516064 (partial info)

```
(3) vim /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

Add User=root
File looks kind of like this
[Service]
User=root
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
(4) Reload and restart kubelet

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Exactly in my case everything worked fine from scratch. So read carefully and check points I highlighted. Most probably you have very tiny problem/typo, cause it works as expected.

I hope my investigation will help you

Comment: thank you for the reply. After I added the proxy settings to `.docker/config.json`, everything works when I run the container directly from the worker node (`docker run ...`), but there is still the same problem when I try to run a pod (`kubectl apply`)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds right & logical, but does not work for me.

I am running kubernetes version "v1.18.6". Data below. This fails. But setting same http-proxy as Env for dockerd, works.

```
admin@str-s6000-acs-13:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d$ sudo cat /proc/$(pidof kubelet)/environ | tr '\0' '\n'      
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
SHELL=/bin/sh
INVOCATION_ID=fd58e75d7be64758b01e2d8d63fdf7f6
JOURNAL_STREAM=9:11737012
KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --network-plugin=cni --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
admin@str-s6000-acs-13:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d$ sudo cat /root/.docker/config.json
{
    "proxies":
    {
        "default":
        {
            "httpProxy": "http://20.72.201.152:3128",
            "httpsProxy": "http://20.72.201.152:3128"
        }
    }
}
admin@str-s6000-acs-13:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d$ 

Apr 12 01:14:49 str-s6000-acs-13 dockerd[27360]: time="2021-04-12T01:14:49.630282308Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /images/create returned error: Get https://sonicanalytics.azurecr.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
```